# Draw on an image in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm fairly new to iPhone app development. I'm trying to make a scrapbook app (for fun sakes) but I can't figure out how to draw on and add pictures to my template which is also an image file (and a UIView). Should I save my template as a pdf? Essentially I don't know how to add stuff to my template - for example draw shapes on it, add a text box, add a picture, etc

Please help!!!!!

Comment: UIImageViews display images, UILabels/UITextViews display text, drawing shapes is more difficult but very easy to look up in Google if you're interested (i.e. iOS draw circles/square/points)

Answer (score 0):

No PDF needed. Check out Quartz 2D:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html

You create a context (e.g., via `CGBitmapContextCreate`), add you bitmap (e.g., via `CGContextDrawImage`), draw text (e.g., via `CGContextShowTextAtPoint`), etc.

Review the Quartz 2D introduction above, and then review some the Quartz 2D code samples. It's not hard, but it's not obvious, either. Just takes a few times to get the hang of it.